# Verification not working

Tags: php

So I'm trying to get a user verified via email (which is sent out perfectly), but when they click the link it says "not inserted". Which is obviously because I wrote something wrong in the insert area, but I'm not quite sure what it could be. Here is my script:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.inc.php';


$Username = $_GET['usr'];
$Code = $_GET['verify'];
$One = '1';

$sql = "SELECT Username, `VerficationCode`, `Verified` FROM user WHERE `Username`='$Username'";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $ActualCode = $row['VerficationCode'];

        if ($Code == $ActualCode) {

            $confirm = "INSERT INTO user (VerficationCode) VALUES ('$One') WHERE `Username` = '$Username'";
            if(!mysqli_query($con,$confirm)){
                $_SESSION['failed'] = 'Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again.';
                echo 'not inserting.';
            } else {
                header ('Location: home.php');
                $_SESSION['verified'] = 'Successfully verified.';
            }
        } else {

            $_SESSION['verified'] = 'Unsuccessfully verified.';
            header ('Location: index.php');
            echo 'unsuccessful';
        }
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['failed'] = 'Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again.';
    header ('failed.php');
}


?>
```

And here is my connect.inc.php script:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "users");

?>
```

Edit: This is what the verification link looks like:               `http://********.com/home.php?verify=friendov59c806e6bfc57TimerHotel20001&usr=TimerHotel`

Comment: `WHERE Username = '$Username'`, you can't use a `where` on an insert. This also is open to SQL injections, parameterize.

Comment: You are using `where` in an insert statement, that will not work. Are you trying to update an existing row or insert a new row?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: And yeah, you can't use WHERE on an INSERT. If you want to change the values in an existing row, use UPDATE. You maybe need to take a basic SQL tutorial. And if you'd echo'd the output of mysqli_error() after your query fails, you'd have seen the syntax error.

Comment: also a security fail - using the username in the verification URL. Leaking usernames over the wire just creates a data source for hackers to attack your login system (which, if it's anything like the code here, will be fairly easy to break into). Your verification code should already be unique and be sufficient to match the user without transmitting the username as well. It looks like setting it to 1 is an attempt to invalidate it, but you should keep it for audit purposes and set another boolean field instead to indicate that the code has been used.

Comment: And this: `header ('Location: index.php');
            echo 'unsuccessful';` makes no sense. You've just redirected the user away from this script. You can't then echo something back to them in this script - they aren't looking at it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
"INSERT INTO user (VerficationCode) VALUES ('$One') WHERE `Username` = '$Username'"
```

use

```
"UPDATE user SET `VerficationCode`='$One' WHERE `Username` = '$Username'"
```

Comment: But using varialbles without `mysql_real_escape_string` is unsafe (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Thanks! It works. I've only recently gotten into PHP and I'm doing stuff way ahead of my progress, but in the end I learn faster that way, that's why I do it. Just fyi :P